# PCL-ROS run time error while doing plane segmentation

Tags: ros, pcl, shared-ptr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am trying to do plane segmentation using PCL and ROS. I am using the sensor Asus xtion pro live. I was able to launch openni_kinect and got the sensor pumping out necessary coordinates.

Here is my program:

ros::Publisher pub;
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr downsampled,output;   



void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
pcl::PointCloud::Ptr output_p(new pcl::PointCloud);
pcl::PointCloud::Ptr downsampled_XYZ(new pcl::PointCloud);
 output_p->width  = 15;
  output_p->height = 1;
  output_p->points.resize (output_p->width * output_p->height);

downsampled_XYZ->width  = 15;
  downsampled_XYZ->height = 1;
  downsampled_XYZ->points.resize (output_p->width * output_p->height);


pcl::VoxelGrid sor;
sor.setInputCloud (input);
sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
sor.filter (*downsampled);
// Change from type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to pcl::PointXYZ
pcl::fromROSMsg (*downsampled, *downsampled_XYZ);
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices ());
// Create the segmentation object
      pcl::SACSegmentation seg;
      // Optional
      seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
      // Mandatory
      seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
      seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
      seg.setMaxIterations (1000);
      seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);

      // Create the filtering object
      pcl::ExtractIndices extract;

      // Segment the largest planar component from the cloud
      seg.setInputCloud (downsampled_XYZ);
      seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
      if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
          {
              std::cerr width * output_p->height  ("output/points", 100);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}

so the run time error is:

```
: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr::reference boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_ >, boost::shared_ptr::reference = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_ >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted
```

I am aware of the shared pointer issue through this post http://answers.ros.org/question/39818/ros-pcl-run-time-error-segmenting-planes/ . As a matter of fact the code developed is based on this.

I know the answer is very near ,Can you guys please help me out on this?.
Thanks.

regards,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51347/pcl-ros-run-time-error-while-doing-plane-segmentation./) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you haven't figured it out already (or it's an omission in your code copying), it looks like the `downsampled` cloud pointer has not been initialized with a valid cloud. You pass the dereferenced shared pointer in the `sor.filter(*downsampled)` line...

At some point, you need: `downsampled.reset(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2)`

In addition, the output cloud pointer has not been initialized, so the call to `pcl::toROSMsg(*output_p, *output)` will also generate an error.

If that is not the problem, you'll probably have to provide some more information (like a backtrace from gdb or something)...

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [jlowenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2599/jlowenz/) with karma: 36 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on 2013-01-03**:
downsampled->width  = 15;
downsampled->height = 1;
output->width=15;
output->height=1; As you can see I did the intialization,but it  still shows the same run-time error.

**Comment by [jlowenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2599/jlowenz/) on 2013-01-03**:
Except that the code you posted says `downsampled_XYZ->width = 15; ...` and I still don't see where you call `new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` anywhere.